# Is this sequence of function uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $C[0,1]=\{ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \mid f \text{ is continuous} \}$ equipped with sup norm $\lVert f \rVert_\infty =  \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \lvert f(x) \rvert$.
I don't know that a sequence function $f_n(x) = -nx+1$ in $(C[0,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty)$ is convergent or not.
I try to show this sequence function is Cauchy sequence.
Let $ \varepsilon >0  $. Choose $ N = $ _______ . Let $ m,n \geq N  $. Then 
$\lVert f_n - f_m \rVert  = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x) \rvert  $
$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x) \rvert= \sup_{x\in[0,1]}  \lvert (m-n)x \rvert = ??  $$
How should I do?

Comment: try to plug into $f_n(x)$ different values of $x\in [0,1]$ and compute the limits...

Comment: I have rarely seen a worse title. What does it mean, for a single function, to *uniform converge*?

Comment: Sorry. Please forgive me for my english skill. Now I have already edited my title.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n(1)$ diverges, this sequence can't even converge pointwise to any real function, not to mention uniform convergence.

Comment: If I change the function to $f_n(x) = -nx+1 $ when $x \in [0, \dfrac{1}{n}]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ when $x \in [\dfrac{1}{n},1]$, the new function is also convergent or not.